# ¿Es posible agregar un Objeto dentro de un Child(Obj) en firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

Actualmente estoy empezando a utilizar `firebase` y quiero implementar una base de datos en mi app de `Android`, estoy tratando de subir dos Objetos, por ahora he subido un Objeto de tipo Persona de la siguiente forma:

en `OnCreate`:

```
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDataBaseReference = . 
 mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Personas");
```

Después para agregar mi objeto en la base de datos:

```
mClientesDataBaseReference.push().setValue(nuevaPersona);
```

Logrando subir esto:

```
personas : {
 "dsgasdgjbnakjds" : {
      "Nombre" : "Lalo",
      "FotoId" : "1",
      "edad" : "18",

      } 
 }
```

Mi objeto es algo parecido a esto:

```
     public Cliente(){
         //Variables de tipo String
         nombre = "";
         FotoId = "";
         Edad = "";
         // Variable tipo Mascota
         mastoca = new Mascota();
    }

    public Mascota{
      //String
      Nombre = "";
      Edad= "";
    }
```

Sin embargo, incluso declarando la mascota como parte del Objeto de `Persona`, esta no aparece en la base de datos.

Me gustaria poder agregar el Objeto(`mascota`) dentro de este mismo Objeto de `persona` y lograr algo parecido a esto:

```
personas : {
 "lksdjnflkasdg" : {
      "Nombre" : "Lalo",
      "FotoId" : "1",
      "edad" : "18",
      "Mascota" : {
           "nombreMascota" : "LittleDog",
           "edadMascota" : 3
      } 
 }, 
 "lkjndslfknlksdn" : {
      "Nombre" : "Roberto",
      "FotoId" : "2",
      "edad" : "20",
      "Mascota" : {
           "nombreMascota" : "LittleDog",
           "edadMascota" : 5
      } 
}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El objeto se debería persistir si cumple con la reglas que exige Firebase.
1) Tener un constructor vacío
2) Tener getter publico para cada propiedad que queres persistir

Si el objeto padre así como los objetos embebidos cumplen con las reglas se van a persistir ( y poder recuperar despues desde el snapshot) automáticamente.